# Applying RFE to make predictions

Tags: r

Im following this sample code to use RFE on my own dataset:

```
# ensure the results are repeatable
set.seed(7)
# load the library
library(mlbench)
library(caret)
# load the data
data(PimaIndiansDiabetes)
# define the control using a random forest selection function
control <- rfeControl(functions=rfFuncs, method="cv", number=10)
# run the RFE algorithm
results <- rfe(PimaIndiansDiabetes[,1:8], PimaIndiansDiabetes[,9], sizes=c(1:8), rfeControl=control)
# summarize the results
print(results)
# list the chosen features
predictors(results)
# plot the results
plot(results, type=c("g", "o"))
```

I can get the RFE portion to work as required and everything plots as needed, but it is unclear to me as to how I take this model and use it to make predictions on new data. I can easily obtain the RMSE of the RFE results, but that metric is only from the trained model; I now need to apply it to a test set and then obtain the RMSE of the results based on applying RFE to the test set.

If Im mistaken about this process please help me understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
newpredictions<-predict(results,PimaIndiansDiabetes_Test[,1:8])
```

(where `PimaIndiansDiabetes_Test` is your test set)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help

Comment: Just one more thing, are you really sure you want to use RMSE for classification?

Comment: Im not using it for classification - Im using LmFuncs as the method. One more question: why would I use [,1:8]? Those are the X values. Where would I represent the dependent variable [,9] in the prediction?

Comment: You predict based on the X values, don't you?

Comment: yes, it just seems like I should have the predicted (y-hat) values somewhere.

Comment: You will use the y-hat values when you will compare the predictions to the real values, am I wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108571/discussion-between-adiana-and-dataguy).